# (Pandas) Compare values of a column to another column, if they match, -1 to quantity column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to substract an item from my inventory dataframe called inventory_df. I have three columns,
SKU, PRODUCT NAME, QUANTITY

I managed to create a list out of the thing I sold in shopify and now I want to compare the SKUs sold, now in a Series called products_to_remove and if they match, -1 to QUANTITY.

```
    export_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Gino Leone\OneDrive\Python 
    programs\Sharp\Inventory\orders_export.csv")
    inventory_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Gino Leone\OneDrive\Python 
    programs\Sharp\Inventory\INVENTORY_DF.csv")


    #Start by working with export_df first

    new_data = export_df.loc[export_df["Lineitem fulfillment status"] == 
    "pending"]

    #Create a new df called sku containing only the rows with valid skus 
    #in long format (FT12-FL12)
    sku = new_data["Lineitem sku"].dropna()

    #Convert into a dataframe made of two columns
    skus_split = sku.str.split('-', expand=True)

    #Create a series containing a list of total skus to retreive
    products_to_remove = skus_split[0].append(skus_split[1])
```

Comment: please provide your code in the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.